# Threads and Audio Play on the same time

Tags: android, multithreading, playback

How can I play two or more audio file in Android? I had created a Class which extending Thread and have a MediaPlayer. I can hear only one audio channel, but all of the threads are running and I should to hear all of the channels, not only one.

Mybe a thread catch the hardware sound card and never get it to the other? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SoundPool` for overlapping audio.